# Example of loopback interface redirection to read the authorized code from oauth URI

Tags: oauth-2.0, loopback, rfc

I am working on an desktop based Java Swing application on which I have to invoke the web browser for authenticate and get the authorization code from that URI.

I was going through https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252 RFC and read the "loopback interface redirection" terminology. Able to find the theocratical concept around this on Net but not able to find any example code.

Can someone help me to understand this better from code perspective or link to any example?

Answer (score 2):

I have some code samples you can easily run from your local PC but they are not coded in Java. Hopefully they help you to understand how the solution works though:

- [Desktop Sample using Loopback Server to Receive Login Response](https://authguidance.com/2018/01/11/desktop-apps-overview/)
- [Desktop Sample using Private URI Scheme to Receive Login Response](https://authguidance.com/2018/01/26/final-desktop-sample-overview/)

The [Nimbus OAuth Libraries](https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-oauth-openid-connect-sdk) might prove useful for a Java implementation.

Comment: Thanks @Gary Archer for detailed explanation. This helps me to understand for Java application and able to implement in Java. The main concepts to implement in Java is to start a socket on any random port and from API side return 303(SEE_OTHER) status code from API to that localhost opened port.

Answer (score 0):

We have achieved this after using the RFC 7636 https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636 where in Java application,  we are starting the inbuilt java http server on random port.

After starting the local server, we generate one random string called code_verifier and then client change it to code_challenge = BASE64URL-ENCODE(SHA256(ASCII(code_verifier))) using SHA256 and create Bas64 encoded URL string and open the browser to do the authentication.

Once authentication is done from browser, webservice creates an auth token against the JWT token and store in DB along with code_challange.

Browser pass the auth token to client and after receiving the response, then client pass the auth token along with code_verifier to get the authorization JWT token. Webserver verifies both the entries against the stored info and passed back the authorization token after successful verification.